# Sqoop error on data fetch from Oracle Database using Oracle wallet

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc, sqoop, sqoop2

```
sqoop import -D mapred.map.child.java.opts='-Doracle.net.tns_admin=. -Doracle.net.wallet_location=.' -files $HOME/wallet/cwallet.sso,$HOME/wallet/ewallet.p12,$HOME/wallet/sqlnet.ora,$HOME/wallet/tnsnames.ora --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST2 --table SQOOP_TEST
```

Am using this sqoop command to fetch data from Oracle DB but ending with below error

> ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified

My Wallet:
**tnsnames.ora**

```
TEST2=   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (server=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME = HDPTEST )
    )   )
```

Wallet works fine,

> $sqlplus /@TEST2
>
> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Jun 8 14:48:42 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release
>   11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
>
> SQL>

JDBC without uding wallet works fine,

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521/HDPTEST

**Detailed Log**

```
Warning: /usr/local/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.

Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/06/08 15:06:15 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/06/08 15:06:15 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG tool.BaseSqoopTool: Enabled debug logging.
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Loaded manager factory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop can be called by Sqoop!
17/06/08 15:06:16 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Trying ManagerFactory: com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.DefaultManagerFactory: Trying with scheme: jdbc:oracle:thin
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.OracleManager$ConnCache: Instantiated new connection cache.
17/06/08 15:06:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG sqoop.ConnFactory: Instantiated ConnManager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager@1d2adfbe
17/06/08 15:06:16 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM SQOOP_TEST t WHERE 1=0
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnInfoRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM SQOOP_TEST t WHERE 1=0
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Creating a new connection for jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST2, using username: null
17/06/08 15:06:16 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: No connection paramenters specified. Using regular API for making connection.
17/06/08 15:06:16 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified 
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:662)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:560)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.makeConnection(OracleManager.java:325)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Unknown host specified 
    at oracle.net.resolver.HostnameNamingAdapter.resolve(HostnameNamingAdapter.java:207)
    at oracle.net.resolver.NameResolver.resolveName(NameResolver.java:131)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:476)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 24 more
17/06/08 15:06:16 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Please help me out to find where am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, and osdt_cert.jar in the classpath and also please check out the "[SSL with JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf)"  whitepaper for more details(page 9). Also, the Wallet location can be specified as part of the tnsnames.ora as shown here.

```
LISTENER = (ADDRESS_LIST=  
 (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=servername)(PORT=2484)) 
)  WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(
DIRECTORY=/server/wallet/path))
```

)

Comment: export HADOOP_OPTS="-Doracle.net.tns_admin=<path> -Doracle.net.wallet_location=<wallet path>" resolved this issue. Thank you for referring that document, i did more work using the same.